# How to configure an embedded Jetty with HTTP/3 via API?

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty, quic, http3, alpn

I'm trying to implement a HTTP/3 using embedded Jetty with Java API. I have a running Jetty with HTTP/2 support, valid certificate on HTTPS default ports. I'm following the code [in Jetty the documentation](https://eclipse.dev/jetty/documentation/jetty-10/programming-guide/index.html#pg-server-http-connector-protocol-http3) but it does not use HTTP/3. This look like:

```
    SslContextFactory.Server sslContextFactory = ...
    // Create and configure the HTTP/3 connector.
    HTTP3ServerConnectionFactory http3 = new HTTP3ServerConnectionFactory( httpConfig );
    HTTP3ServerConnector http3Connector = new HTTP3ServerConnector( this, sslContextFactory, http3 );
    http3Connector.setPort( 443 );
    addConnector( http3Connector );
```

From the [follow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77317395/java-lang-illegalstateexception-no-pem-work-directory-configured) I add also a pem directory:

```
    Path pemDir = ...;
    Files.createDirectories( pemDir );
    http3Connector.getQuicConfiguration().setPemWorkDirectory( pemDir );
```

For HTTP/3 I add the follow extra libraries to my Jetty installation:

- org.eclipse.jetty.http3:http3-server:10.0.17
- org.eclipse.jetty.http3:http3-common:10.0.17
- org.eclipse.jetty.http3:http3-qpack:10.0.17
- org.eclipse.jetty.quic:quic-server:10.0.17
- org.eclipse.jetty.quic:quic-common:10.0.17
- org.eclipse.jetty.quic:quic-quiche-common:10.0.17
- org.eclipse.jetty.quic:quic-quiche-jna
- net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.11.0
- org.mortbay.jetty.quiche:jetty-quiche-native:0.18.0

If I test it with [curl-http3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77388689/12631) then it work. If I test it with Chrome and Edge then it is ignored. Firefox does not load the application. With Firefox and Wireshark I see a quic communication.

I have test it with Java 11 and Java 17.

What I doing wrong? I am missing a library or some settings?

Comment: For HTTP/3 I would recommend using Jetty 12 instead.  See https://eclipse.dev/jetty/documentation/jetty-12/programming-guide/index.html#pg-server-http3 - Sorry for just a link to documentation, but I do not understand what you are doing with your code.

Comment: This link to a complete other topic with low level HTTP/3 API. The equivalent link for Jetty is https://eclipse.dev/jetty/documentation/jetty-12/programming-guide/index.html#pg-server-http-connector-protocol-http3 - But there is no other information as for Jetty 10. Because the servlet package problem we can switch currently.